# Join and split multiple buffers into single buffer - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to piece of code which picks up data from MongoDB and dumps it into Redis in terms of raw buffers.

However instead of JSON documents, I am fetching raw `buffer` using a MongoDB stream. Since dumping each buffer into Redis separately will be an expensive task in terms of number of keys in Redis, I plan to reduce this by storing multiple raw buffers into the same key. This essentially means that I am trying to store an array of `buffer` objects. Thus, by doing this I am creating a JS object which looks like

`[<Buffer 61 62 63 64 .. >, <Buffer 61 62 63 65 ..>, <Buffer 61 62 63 64...> ...]`

where each document is represented by a `buffer` object.

Since this is an array, I want to convert it a single buffer which can be directly put into a Redis key. One way I tried was to use the `concat` method to merge buffers and separators also in between. However this might not be the best way as it might lead to conflicts.

Thus I need a way to transform this array of buffers into single buffer and also a way to retrieve them back.

Looking for the methods -

1. `MergeArrayBuffer([<Buffer>, <Buffer> ..])` => `<Buffer>`
2. `MergedBufferToArray(<Buffer>)` => `[<Buffer>, <Buffer> ..]`

Comment: Have you considered saving them in a Redis LIST / SET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice user land module for this written by Rod Vagg, see https://github.com/rvagg/bl

Comment: Great! Seems to solve the issue. Trying it out. Thanks!